# Installing Wordnet module perl in Windows 10

Tags: windows, perl, perl-module

i used the command

```
cpanm WordNet::Similarity
```

the first time it generate error for installing the dependencies  wiht the package

WordNet::QueryData and the problem seem to be described byt this error message

> *** Please set the WNHOME environment variable to the location of your**
>      WordNet installation.  QueryData.pm will not work otherwise.
>    **Alternatively, you can make the installation in the default
>   ***   location, C:\Program Files\WordNet\3.0 on Windows, or /usr/local/WordNet-3.0 on unix.

i donwloaded the last version for windows the version 2.1 i instaled it in C:\Program Files (x86)\WordNet\2.1

the first problem is that they haven't the same name so impossible that the instalation find this location

and the proposed solution is to set

> WNHOME environment variable (specifying the WordNet
>   installation directory).

how to set the WNHOME? because i set the PATH in the environnment variable to the location and i have the same problem

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking [how to set environment variables in Windows](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

Comment: maybe, i am not sure of the problem because i already set the environement variable (PATH) and it doesn'twork

Comment: `PATH` is not the same as `WNHOME`. It tells you to set `WNHOME`, so you should set `WNHOME`.

Comment: You *MUST* learn how to use your chosen OS and development environment before trying your hand at programming. There are no two ways about it.

Comment: @SinanÜnür your answers is not in the topic, if you have a constructiv idea, so tell it, because i know variable environement and all what you speak about, it just only problem of english ;)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot thank you this help me because i was confused with the WNHOME, i was thinking windows home

Comment: @NarimenDal Mine was not an answer, it was a comment. You asked how to set an environment variable. You need to know that stuff before you can program. It is just the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is very simple, it is not the the PATH, but you must create  new variable one WNHOME (for example    C:\Program Files\WordNet\2.1)it is for the folder of wordnet (WN)) and another variable WNSEARCHDIR for the dictionnary ex: C:\Program Files\WordNet\2.1\dict